# java.lang.NullPointerException: MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-geofence

I am working on geofencing , and trying to initialize map but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference

I also tried all the solutions that I found on stackoverflow but I could not find the solution to my problem.

```
 private void initGMaps(){
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

        // initialize GoogleMaps

        initGMaps();

        // create GoogleApiClient
        createGoogleApi();
    }

<!--GoogleMap fragment-->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.utkukayman.locationbasedreminderbyutku, PID: 22875
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.utkukayman.locationbasedreminderbyutku/com.utkukayman.locationbasedreminderbyutku.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
>           at com.utkukayman.locationbasedreminderbyutku.MapsActivity.initGMaps(MapsActivity.java:188)
>           at com.utkukayman.locationbasedreminderbyutku.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:82)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>   Application terminated.

Can anyone help me? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for that it is all about my stupid fault .

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   ----->it should be activity_maps

Answer (score 3):

You're inflating `SupportMapFragment`, not `MapFragment`.

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` inside an activity and cast `findFragment()` result to `SupportMapFragment`.

Your activity needs to extend `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity` depending on your use case.

Comment: It stil turns null exception on SupportMapFragment , it also shows error on onCreate method. I think that error is about where to initiliaze map , do you have any idea about that ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: First check if the map fragment is actually loading. Comment `initGMaps()` and start the activity. It shouldn't crash so check if you can see the map in the middle of Atlantic Ocean. Also make sure the `<fragment android:id="@+id/map>` is inside `layout/activity_main.xml`.